# NavigatorContent onSelect

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Is there any shortcut way to add an eventListener to something like a select event for NavigatorContent.

I am aware I can add a listener for a change event on the ViewStack and identify the selected NavigatorContent through that handler.

Comment: What is it exactly you are trying to achieve?
Do you want to retrieve  the selected NavigatorContent item in your viewstack?

Answer (score 1):

The ViewStack component [dispatch a CREATION_COMPLETE event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/ViewStack.html#selectedChild) on the new selectedChild

Answer (score 0):

As2 has shortcuts for what you want, im afraid as3 doesnt as AS3 wants to know exactly whats needed to care for at what time.

an update /enterframe function can reduce some code but apply more load on the swf over all as its waitng for a call.

throw some code up in your question so we all know exactly what your talking about.